# Is this way to implement an interface with constructor in TS is wrong/right?

Tags: typescript

I am absolute newbie in TS (and mostly in JS too). I read ["Difference between the static and instance sides of classes"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes) in Typescript handbook which says that constructor should be separated into another interface and fabric function should be used. So, I tried another solution which is simpler, obvious and IMHO more classical:

```
interface ClockInterface {
    tick(): void;
    init(hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}

class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
    hour: number;
    minutes: number;
    init(h: number, m: number) {
        this.hour = h;
        this.minutes = m;
        return this;
    }
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { return this.init(h, m); }
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tock", this.hour, this.minutes);
    }
}

let analog = new AnalogClock(7, 32);
analog.tick();
```

It seems to work, but I don't know, is this approach OK or it has some problems that I do not notice?

Comment: It's unnecessarily complicated, and I think you've misconstrued what you read. You only need to separate it out if you need to specify the constructor in the interface, which I would call a code smell: interfaces are about *behavior*. I'm not sure your version is any better: all your constructor does is call init. You've just pushed the problem back a step.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small number args like this, it might make it simpler if you set the fields directly in the constructor:

```
interface IClockInterface {
  tick(): void;
}

class AnalogClock implements IClockInterface {
  constructor(private hour: number, private minutes: number) {}
  public tick(): void {
    console.log("tick tock", this.hour, this.minutes);
  }
}

let analog = new AnalogClock(7, 32);
analog.tick();
```

But if you have many args, would be cleaner if you turn them into an input object with its own interface:

```
interface IClockInterface {
  tick(): void;
}

interface IAnalogClockParams {
  hour: number;
  minutes: number;
}

class AnalogClock implements IClockInterface {
  constructor(private params: IAnalogClockParams) {}
  public tick(): void {
    const { hour, minutes } = this.params;
    console.log("tick tock", hour, minutes);
  }
}

let analog = new AnalogClock({ hour: 7, minutes: 32 });
analog.tick();
```

Sometimes for any reason you may decided that you have to have the fields actually on the class and there is a lot of them. In such cases you can avoid calling `this.x = x; this.y = y ....` many times using `Object.assign`:

```
interface IAnalogClockParams {
  hour: number;
  minutes: number;
}

interface IClockInterface extends IAnalogClockParams {
  tick(): void;
}

class AnalogClock implements IClockInterface {
  public hour!: number;
  public minutes!: number;
  constructor(private params: IAnalogClockParams) {
    Object.assign<this, IAnalogClockParams>(this, params);
  }
  public tick(): void {
    const { hour, minutes } = this.params;
    console.log("tick tock", hour, minutes);
  }
}

let analog = new AnalogClock({ hour: 7, minutes: 32 });
analog.tick();
```